# How to deserialize an xml that has no namespace, etc...?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file that looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
 <node id="1" />
</config>
```

Now I try to deserialize it, but always get the error :

```
<config xmlns=''> was not expected
```

Anyone how to fix this ? I dont have any control over the xml.

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

Why not just load it in as a DOM (e.g. using `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`) and extract the data yourself? Assuming it wasn't saved with `XmlSerializer`, there's no point in trying to *deserialize* it that way.

EDIT: It would help if you'd give us some background here. If this isn't a valid XmlSerializer output, what is it? Was it originally a valid file, but something has stripped out the namespaces? If so, what else has it done?

You may well be able to get away with just reapplying the namespace everywhere yourself (to every element) although that may be annoying do. Currently we can't really tell though.

Comment: I just posted an example, the file is actually pretty big and I have to use the XmlSerializer for deserialize.

Comment: @eemceebee: *Why* do you have to use `XmlSerializer`? If it's not a valid output from `XmlSerializer`, why would you try to use that to deserialize?

Comment: @CJohnson: Not really - there's not enough information IMO. If you think there is, feel free to answer it of course.